# Web Service Implementation Changes

Tags: web-services, versioning, soa

To what degree should web service providers limit implementation changes without creating a new service version?  One view is that as long as the contract is upheld, the service owner should be free to update the implementation as needed.  Schemas are not always air tight and it is foreseeable that changes within the service implementation affect the service output while still upholding the contract.

To what degree should consumers be notified of implementation changes?  Its one thing to notify consumers of updates to your own web service implementation.  How feasible is it to track implementation changes to all downstream dependencies?  Should service owners create a new version when they know that a change may affect consumers?  And try to be a good citizen and notify consumers of all other changes?

Lots of questions and I doubt there is one size fits all answer.  It could just depend on the situation.  Maybe this is what SLAs are for.

Answer (score 1):

Good questions, and I think you've already answered it. Yes, these details would be in an SLA and I think that if the contract/WSDL is the same that why would the service need to notify its' consumers? Unless of course changes to the service impact response times and performance. Maybe the service would notify consumers when another contract is introduced (in addition to the original). Consumers become aware of any new capabilities and can adjust their clients accordingly if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in an environment where SLAs don't exist for internal clients, so absent an SLA, the following are some common sense guidelines

1. Attempt to limit number of modifications to services
2. Communicate service implementation releases so consumers can plan test cycles
3. Provide consumers with the list of direct downstream dependencies and location to find their schedules and release notes
4. Consider a new version if an implementation change will semantically affect consumer

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on your specific circumstances. Speaking generally, here are a few top considerations.

The service contract and schema are all that a service and client share in common. A service implementation change that does not change the contract or schema (e.g., fixing a bug in the implementation logic) should not necessitate notifying the clients, nor should it be considered a new version.

OTOH, if you have a poorly constructed, overly-loose contract, such as passing all of the data as one big string, where the client had to do extensive interpretation to consume the service, and now you're looking to exploit that overly-loose contract in a way that would likely break the client, you owe it to all parties to change the contract (and improve it!) and publish that as a new version of the service.

Since services are often used to enable loose coupling between services, it is sometimes not practical or even possible to identify all of the clients of a service. Producing a new version of a service in these situations often entails maintaining multiple versions of a service for some period of time, often as directed by some governance body.

Providing details about service implementations, implementation dependencies, etc., encourages creating tight coupling by disclosing non-contract related details that the client may then take a dependency on. That can limit the ability of the service to change independently of the client.

The book [Web Service Contract Design and Versioning for SOA](http://www.soabooks.com/wsc/) 
by Thomas Erl is a good resource on the topic, and details several common scenarios.